# Excel #DIV/0! issue with calculating increase

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula in cell "D2"

=IF((C2-$B2)/$B2>0.2,1,0)

In short in column D I want to return a "1" if the value in Column C is 20% or more than the value in Column B or "0" if not.

For row 2 it works perfectly.  However, for row 3 it returns a #DIV/0! due to column B being 0 but I would like it to return a "1" as the value in column C is more than 20% than the value in column B.  For row 4 I would like to return a "0" as column C is not more than 20% than the value in column B.

[image]

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple inequation. [Multiply both parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation#Properties) by $B2 and you'll skip the division by 0 problem. Like this:

```
=IF((C2-$B2)>0.2*$B2,1,0)
```

Also, you can make it a little shorter taking off the IF function (and the extra brackets i previously left there to make it easier to compare):

```
=(C2-$B2>0.2*$B2)*1
```